# launch new window, return back result to textbox on parent page

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to launch new window, return back result to textbox on the parent page.  I have control over both pages obviously so I can add any javascript etc. that might be required.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Run a function on the parent window or otherwise communicate with it from code in the pop up window  using `window.opener`